# Angular typescript, cannot push to an array. Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, undefined

I am new to angular and my JavaScript is basic. I am trying to write a program the solves Sudoku puzzles. A 9x9 grid will have 81 points or squares. I figured that I could check for violations of Sudoku rules (no repeats of a number within a single row, column, or 3x3 by sector) faster if I organized the points into three identical lists of 81, but organized three different ways. Again, by column, row, and sector.

So: I would like an Array that contains three Arrays that contains nine Arrays that contains nine points.

I know that the `Array<Array<Point>>` has a length of 9. I declared it as such and when I double check with a console log, it seems it has a length of 9. So I was thinking that there is 9 nulls `Array<Point>` within. I figured I could just push points to any of those 9 Arrays, but I have no luck. I keep getting told that `grid[0][x]` is undefined. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
  gridByX:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9);
  gridByY:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9);
  gridByS:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9);
  grid:Array<Array<Array<Point>>> = [this.gridByX, this.gridByY, this.gridByS];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateGrid();
  }

  populateGrid(){
    let counter = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++){
      for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        let point = new Point(counter, x, y);
        this.grid[0][x].push(point);
        this.grid[1][y].push(point);
        this.grid[2][point.sector].push(point);


      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you create a `new Array(n)`, it creates an array with `n` undefined elements. Then, you can assign elements using bracket notation (eg: `array[x] = new Point()`). 
Also, you can only call `.push` on arrays. In this case, your syntax should look like: `grid[0][x] = new Point(counter, x, y)`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but grid[0][x] is an Array<Point>. I don't think it can be defined as a single point like grid[0][x] = new Point(counter, x, yz). But you are right about the undefined elements, but if I create a new Array each loop i'm just going to be stuck with an Array of one rather an Array of 9 points like I am aiming for. I guess I need to check if the array is undefined, if so create one, but if not, push the point.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. You will need to define grid[0][x] first in your loop before pushing elements to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 gridByX:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9);
  gridByY:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9);
  gridByS:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9);
  grid:Array<Array<Array<Point>>> = [this.gridByX, this.gridByY, this.gridByS];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateGrid();
  }

  populateGrid(){
    let counter = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++){
      for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        let point = new Point(counter, x, y);

        grid[0][x] = grid[0][x] || [];
        grid[0][x].push(point);

        grid[1][y] = grid[1][y] || [];
        grid[1][y].push(point);

        grid[2][point.sector] = grid[2][point.sector] || [];
        grid[2][point.sector].push(point);
      }
    }
  }
```

Try defining the index property before manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

> So I was thinking that there are 9 null `Array<Point>` within.

This is correct.  However, a *null* array is not the same thing as an *empty* array.  Before you can push to it, you have to instantiate it with an actual array object.

Try this for a three-line solution:

```
gridByX:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9).fill().map(() => []);
gridByY:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9).fill().map(() => []);
gridByS:Array<Array<Point>> = new Array<Array<Point>>(9).fill().map(() => []);
```

`fill` with no argument initializes it with 9 `undefined` values, which are then replaced with empty arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I knew there had to be an easier way. I made some edits so that if the array is undefined, it is instantiated, then a point is added. If the array is defined, it will be added. Think this solves things, but if not I will definitely use fill, which I did not know existed. Thanks alot!

Comment: Actually, don't do that, I forgot that `fill` has funny behavior when you use it with objects (which includes sub-arrays).  I'll update my answer with a better short solution.

Comment: (if you're curious, the original solution would have filled it with nine references to the same array, so pushing a value to one of them would push it to all nine)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `this` outside of an instance scope, so the line:
`grid:Array<Array<Array<Point>>> = [this.gridByX, this.gridByY, this.gridByS];`
cannot be assigned as a class property

just leave `grid:Array<Array<Array<Point>>>;` for property declaration and make the assignment in the `constructor() {}` call